# Why does a list of values not cool on the LLVM backend of K?

Tags: kframework

When trying to define the syntax for a Scheme-like language, I found that the running result of kompiled file with java backend

```
kompile --backend java scheme.k -d .
```

behaves differently with llvm backend

```
kompile --backend llvm scheme.k -d .
```

Here's my code for scheme.k:

```
module SCHEME-COMMON
  imports DOMAINS-SYNTAX

  syntax Name ::= "+" | "-" | "*" | "/"
                | "display" | "newline"

  syntax Names ::= List{Name," "}

  syntax Exp ::= Int | Bool | String | Name
               | "[" Name Exps "]"                 [strict(2)]

  syntax Exps  ::= List{Exp," "}                   [strict]
  syntax Val
  syntax Vals ::= List{Val," "}
  syntax Bottom
  syntax Bottoms ::= List{Bottom," "}

  syntax Pgm ::= Exp Pgm            [strict(1)] 
               | "eof"

endmodule


module SCHEME-SYNTAX
  imports SCHEME-COMMON
  imports BUILTIN-ID-TOKENS

  syntax Name ::= r"[a-z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*"           [token, prec(2)]
                | #LowerId                        [token]
endmodule


module SCHEME-MACROS
  imports SCHEME-COMMON

endmodule


module SCHEME
  imports SCHEME-COMMON
  imports SCHEME-MACROS
  imports DOMAINS

  configuration <T color="yellow">
                  <k color="green"> $PGM:Pgm </k>
                  <env color="violet"> .Map </env>
                  <store color="white"> .Map </store>
                  <input color="magenta" stream="stdin"> .List </input>
                  <output color="brown" stream="stdout"> .List </output>
                </T>

  syntax Val ::= Int | Bool | String
  syntax Exp ::= Val
  syntax Exps ::= Vals
  syntax Vals ::= Bottoms
  syntax Exps ::= Names
  syntax Names ::= Bottoms
  syntax KResult ::= Vals | Val

  rule _:Val P:Pgm => P
    when notBool(P ==K eof)
  rule V:Val eof => V

  rule [+ I1 I2 Vals] => [+ (I1 +Int I2) Vals]              [arith]
  rule [+ I .Vals] => I                                     [arith]
  rule [- I1 I2 Vals] => [- (I1 -Int I2) Vals]              [arith]
  rule [- I .Vals] => I                                     [arith]
  rule [* I1 I2 Vals] => [* (I1 *Int I2) Vals]              [arith]
  rule [* I .Vals] => I                                     [arith]
  rule [/ I1 I2 Vals] => [/ (I1 /Int I2) Vals]
    when I2 =/=K 0                                          [arith]
  rule [/ I .Vals] => I                                     [arith]

  rule <k> [newline .Exps] => "" ...</k>
       <output>... .List => ListItem("\n") </output>        [io]

  rule <k> [display V:Val] => "" ...</k>
       <output>... .List => ListItem(V) </output>           [io]

endmodule
```

and this is the test file I'm trying to run:

```
[display 8]
eof
```

Strangely, the kompiled version using java can run this test case normally, while the kompiled version using llvm stucks at

```
<k>
    8  .Bottoms ~> #freezer[__]_SCHEME-COMMON_Exp_Name_Exps0_ ( display ) ~> #freezer___SCHEME-COMMON_Pgm_Exp_Pgm1_ ( eof )
</k>
```

What might be a possible reason? The version information for kompile is

```
RV-K version 1.0-SNAPSHOT
Git revision: a7c2937
Git branch: UNKNOWN  
Build date: Wed Feb 12 09:46:03 CST 2020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the LLVM and Haskell backends, two productions are said to *overload* with one another when they share the same arity and klabel attribute and all the argument sorts of one production are less than or equal to the argument sorts of the other, and the result sort of the first is less than the result of the other. Special consideration is given during matching to terms that overload: For example, in your example, if a list of Exps and a list of Vals were said to overload, then if you have a pattern `V:Vals`, it would match the term `V:Val, .Exps` of sort `Exps`.

By default, the Java backend assumes that all Lists between sorts that have a subsort relationship overload. However, the LLVM and Haskell backends do not make this assumption. Thus, your example will work if you give the same klabel attribute to your Exps List and your Vals list. We do not do the same thing in the llvm backend because we have found that it tends to lead to serious ambiguity in your grammar in places where you do not expect it.

For example:

```
module SCHEME-COMMON
  imports DOMAINS-SYNTAX

  syntax Name ::= "+" | "-" | "*" | "/"
                | "display" | "newline"

  syntax Names ::= List{Name," "}                  [klabel(exps)]

  syntax Exp ::= Int | Bool | String | Name
               | "[" Name Exps "]"                 [strict(2)]

  syntax Exps  ::= List{Exp," "}                   [strict, klabel(exps)]
  syntax Val
  syntax Vals ::= List{Val," "}                    [klabel(exps)]
  syntax Bottom
  syntax Bottoms ::= List{Bottom," "}              [klabel(exps)]

  syntax Pgm ::= Exp Pgm            [strict(1)] 
               | "eof"

endmodule
```

Comment: I kinda got your point, but what does it mean by "give the **same klabel attribute** to your Exps List and your Vals list"? In other words, what do I exactly need to modify in my code in order to get this example work?

Comment: You can add `syntax Exps  ::= List{Exp," "} [strict, klabel(expsList), symbol, overload]` and `syntax Vals ::= List{Val," "} [klabel(expsList), symbol, overload]`.

Comment: I edited the answer with a version of the SCHEME-COMMON module that works correctly.